# Cracks in basement cement that seem to leak more when water is running?

Tags: basement

I came home from a 2 day trip and found cracks in my basement cement with water seeping into them. I noticed that when I ran the water it leaked more, any guess what the problem is?

Comment: where are the cracks in your basement?  do you have pictures?  what amount of water is coming in?

Answer (score 2):

**More leakage when you run the water points firmly to leaking from sewer line.** A leaking water line would, if anything leak less when the water was run (or more likely just not change) since it has water under pressure in it all times.

A sewer line does not have water in it until you run the water, so if the leak leaks more when the water is running, it's from a sewer line. Crude home test method is to toss some food coloring (or unsweetened drink mix, which can be a handy source of strong color) into the toilet and flush, and see if the leak color changes to match (it will generally be more dilute, so use a strong color mix.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a broken water line or sewage line somewhere. It could be in the slab or buried. Get a plumber that specializes in leak detection out there ASAP, and do not consume your water until you get the OK from them.